# Patent specification

Tags: prior-art, claims, expired-patent, us2738257

In reference to the patent: [US 2,738,257](https://www.google.com/patents/US2738257)

Has the patent been granted for the complete method or for the compound mixture?

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer your question, you will need to examine the claims. Most of the claims are detectors and substances, but there are two method claims, shown in full below:

> I claim:
>
> 1. A carbon monoxide detector substance ...
> 2. A detector that ...
> 3. A carbon monoxide detector ...
> 4. A detector which ...
> 5. A detector which ...
> 6. A non-accumulative and self regenerative detector for ...
> 7. A gel which ...
> 8. An accumulative gel for detecting ...
> 9. A non-accumulative gel for detecting ...
> 10. The method of multiplying the darkening effect of palladium
>       compounds upon exposure to carbon monoxide comprising: mixing an
>       indicator from the group consisting of sodium alizarin sulfonate and
>       orthotolidine with an aqueous solution of palladium salt; absorbing
>       the mixed solution on the surface of an inorganic carrier, drying the
>       carrier from 110° F to 135° F and thereafter baking from 280° F to
>       350° F.
> 11. A carbon monoxide detector comprising ...
> 12. The method of photoelectrically detecting carbon monoxide
>       contamination comprising: depositing a light colored reactive
>       substance of mixed sensitivity upon the surface of a granular
>       inorganic translucent carrier which substance darkens upon exposure to
>       carbon monoxide; disposing the substance upon a transparent plate;
>       disposing the plate between the light and photoelectric element of a
>       photoelectric measuring circuit; and continuously exposing the plate
>       to the contaminated atmosphere, said substance having a palladium
>       compound that darkens upon exposure to carbon monoxide and also having
>       a copper compound that resists said darkening and which tends to
>       lighten the substance to render the substance self-regenerating and
>       independent of time of exposure, said mixed sensitivities being
>       obtained by differing the relative proportions of palladium and copper
>       in the substance applied to different granules of carrier.
> 13. A carbon monoxide detector substance formed from ...
> 14. A carbon monoxide detector substance formed as ...
> 15. A tape for use on photoelectric detectors for ...
> 16. A tape as described in claim 15 wherein ...
> 17. A continuous carbon monoxide detector and measurer comprising ...

Please note that this patent is quite old and has been expired for years, so it is in the Public Domain. All of the methods disclosed in the background, as well as those disclosed in the claims, can be considered Prior Art.